# How to add colorbar with perspective plot in R

Tags: r, plot

May be it is very simple to do, but after hours of searching I didn't able to find how to add colorbar beside the persp plot using R. Could anyone kindly help? Thanks.

```
persp(w_lb, w_dti, cm[[i]], 
        theta = -30, phi = 30, expand = 0.95, 
        col=color[facetcol], shade = 0.25, 
        ticktype = "detailed", border = NA, 
        xlab = "LB", ylab = "DT", zlab="CM", 
        zlim=c(0.0, 1.0)
)
```

Comment: Do you need to use `persp`?  `wireframe` in `library(lattice)` has a `colorkey` argument.

Comment: Unfortunately I need persp in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to add a legend using `image.plot` in the `fields` package. Using an example from `?persp`:

```
library(fields)

## persp example code
par(bg = "white")
x <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 30)
y <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 35)
z <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) a*b^2)
nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- (z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz])/4
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30, axes=T, ticktype='detailed')

## add color bar
image.plot(legend.only=T, zlim=range(zfacet), col=color)
```

EDIT thanks to @Marc_in_the_box: the range of the colorbar is defined by `zfacet`, not by `z`
[image: persp with colorbar]

Answer (score 5):

`persp` has a tricky way of computing colors based on the mid points of the facets. This makes your work a bit difficult in extracting the color levels, but I think I have found a way. In any case, `layout` is probably your best bet for splitting your device and adding a color bar:

#### Example:

```
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(4,1), heights=1)
par(bg = "white", mar=c(4,4,1,1))
x <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 30)
y <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 35)
z <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) a*b^2)
nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- (z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz])/4
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30)

labs <- levels(facetcol)
tmp <- cbind(lower = as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", labs) ),
      upper = as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", labs) ))

par(mar=c(10,0,10,5))
image(x=1, y=rowMeans(tmp), matrix(rowMeans(tmp), nrow=1, ncol=nbcol), col=color, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
axis(4)
box()
```

[image]

btw, I realized that the last example from `persp` looks to have an error in it's calculation of facet values - as is, they are the sum of the corner values, and need to be divided by 4 in order to use them directly in extracting the color break points:

```
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)

#should be:
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- (z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]) / 4
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
```

Comment: I think your approach is more correct, because you calculate the value of the facets centers, instead of assuming the color range is stretched from `min(z)` to `max(z)`. For example, your bar start at `min(zfacet) = -6.750447`, while `min(z) = -7.414875`. Will add this to my answer too :)

Comment: Thanks :) along with the comment from @koekenbakker