# R:mgcv add colorbar to 2D heatmap of GAM

Tags: r, heatmap, gam, mgcv

I'm fitting a gam with `mgcv` and plot the result with the default `plot.gam()` function. My model includes a 2D-smoother and I want to plot the result as a heatmap. Is there any way to add a colorbar for the heatmap?

I've previously looked into other GAM potting packages, but none of them provided the necessary visualisation. Please note, this is just a simplification for illustration purposes; the actual model (and reporting needs) is much more complicated

**edited:** I initially had swapped y and z in my tensor product, updated to reflect the correct version both in the code and the plot

```
df.gam<-gam(y~te(x,z), data=df, method='REML')
plot(df.gam, scheme=2, hcolors=heat.colors(999, rev =T), rug=F)
```

[image: 2D GAM heatmap]

sample data:

```
structure(list(x = c(3, 17, 37, 9, 4, 11, 20.5, 11.5, 16, 17, 
18, 15, 13, 29.5, 13.5, 25, 15, 13, 20, 20.5, 17, 11, 11, 5, 
16, 13, 3.5, 16, 16, 5, 20.5, 2, 20, 9, 23.5, 18, 3.5, 16, 23, 
3, 37, 24, 5, 2, 9, 3, 8, 10.5, 37, 3, 9, 11, 10.5, 9, 5.5, 8, 
22, 15.5, 18, 15, 3.5, 4.5, 20, 22, 4, 8, 18, 19, 26, 9, 5, 18, 
10.5, 30, 15, 13, 27, 19, 5.5, 18, 11.5, 23.5, 2, 25, 30, 17, 
18, 5, 16.5, 9, 2, 2, 23, 21, 15.5, 13, 3, 24, 17, 4.5), z = c(144, 
59, 66, 99, 136, 46, 76, 87, 54, 59, 46, 96, 38, 101, 84, 64, 
92, 56, 69, 76, 93, 109, 46, 124, 54, 98, 131, 89, 69, 124, 105, 
120, 69, 99, 84, 75, 129, 69, 74, 112, 66, 78, 118, 120, 103, 
116, 98, 57, 66, 116, 108, 95, 57, 41, 20, 89, 61, 61, 82, 52, 
129, 119, 69, 61, 136, 98, 94, 70, 77, 108, 118, 94, 105, 52, 
52, 38, 73, 59, 110, 97, 87, 84, 119, 64, 68, 93, 94, 9, 96, 
103, 119, 119, 74, 52, 95, 56, 112, 78, 93, 119), y = c(96.535, 
113.54, 108.17, 104.755, 94.36, 110.74, 112.83, 110.525, 103.645, 
117.875, 105.035, 109.62, 105.24, 119.485, 107.52, 107.925, 107.875, 
108.015, 115.455, 114.69, 116.715, 103.725, 110.395, 100.42, 
108.79, 110.94, 99.13, 110.935, 112.94, 100.785, 110.035, 102.95, 
108.42, 109.385, 119.09, 110.93, 99.885, 109.96, 116.575, 100.91, 
114.615, 113.87, 103.08, 101.15, 98.68, 101.825, 105.36, 110.045, 
118.575, 108.45, 99.21, 109.19, 107.175, 103.14, 94.855, 108.15, 
109.345, 110.935, 112.395, 111.13, 95.185, 100.335, 112.105, 
111.595, 100.365, 108.75, 116.695, 110.745, 112.455, 104.92, 
102.13, 110.905, 107.365, 113.785, 105.595, 107.65, 114.325, 
108.195, 96.72, 112.65, 103.81, 115.93, 101.41, 115.455, 108.58, 
118.705, 116.465, 96.89, 108.655, 107.225, 101.79, 102.235, 112.08, 
109.455, 111.945, 104.11, 94.775, 110.745, 112.44, 102.525)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base plot solution would be to use `fields::image.plot` directly. Unfortunately, it require data in a classic wide format, not the long format needed by ggplot.

We can facilitate plotting by grabbing the object returned by `plot.gam()`, and then do a little manipulation of the object to get what we need for `image.plot()`

Following on from @Anke's answer then, instead of plotting with `plot.gam()` then using `image.plot()` to add the legend, we proceed to use `plot.gam()` to get what we need to plot, but do everything in `image.plot()`

```r
plt <- plot(df.gam)
plt <- plt[[1]] # plot.gam returns a list of n elements, one per plot

# extract the `$fit` variable - this is est from smooth_estimates
fit <- plt$fit
# reshape fit (which is a 1 column matrix) to have dimension 40x40
dim(fit) <- c(40,40)
# plot with image.plot
image.plot(x = plt$x, y = plt$y, z = fit, col = heat.colors(999, rev = TRUE))
contour(x = plt$x, y = plt$y, z = fit, add = TRUE)
box()
```

This produces:

[image]

You could also use the `fields::plot.surface()` function

```r
l <- list(x = plt$x, y = plt$y, z = fit)
plot.surface(l, type = "C", col = heat.colors(999, rev = TRUE))
box()
```

This produces:

[image]

See `?fields::plot.surface` for other arguments to modify the contour plot etc.

As shown, these all have the correct range on the colour bar. It would appear that @Anke's version the colour bar mapping is off in all of the plots, but mostly just a little bit so it wasn't as noticeable.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I'm very inexperienced with lists. When I follow your first approach, I still receive a list even when calling the first plot with ```plt <- plt[[1]]```. Not entirely sure what I'm missing, but when I proceed to ```fit <- plt$fit```, this still seems to be in list format. How can I adapt this for multiple smooth terms in my model?

Comment: Also, when I call ```plt <- plot(df.gam)``` it still actually plots it in addition to saving it as an object.

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't paying attention and was trying to pull out normal smooth plots, not 2D surface plots. My bad. But the part where it plots everything while saving to an object remains.

Comment: You can't do anything about that plotting to use this option. There are ways to get what you need from `predict()` with `type = "terms"` or `"iterms"` and then reshape each column of partial effect values into a matrix like I showed above. But you are now also responsible for providing the predictions data you want and you'll like have to do this smooth by smooth separately... Then there is using `mgcv::PredictMat()` to get what you want but then you need to know about the internals of mgcv.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier (IMHO) to do this reliably within the ggplot2 ecosphere.

I'll show a canned approach using my {gratia} package but also checkout {mgcViz}. I'll also suggest a more generic solution using tools from {gratia} to extra information about your model's smooths and then plot them yourself using `ggplot()`.

```r
library('mgcv')
library('gratia')
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')

# load your snippet of data via df <- structure( .... )

# then fit your model (note you have y as response & in the tensor product
# I assume z is the response below and x and y are coordinates
m <- gam(z ~ te(x, y), data=df, method='REML')

# now visualize the mode using {gratia}
draw(m)
```

This produces:

[image]

{gratia}'s `draw()` methods can't plot everything yet, but where it doesn't work you should still be able to evaluate the data you need using tools in {gratia}, which you can then plot with `ggplot()` itself by hand.

To get values for your smooths, i.e. the data behind the plots that `plot.gam()` or `draw()` display, use `gratia::smooth_estimates()`

```r
# dist controls what we do with covariate combinations too far
# from support of the data. 0.1 matches mgcv:::plot.gam behaviour
sm <- smooth_estimates(m, dist = 0.1)
```

yielding

```r
r$> sm                                                                          
# A tibble: 10,000 × 7
   smooth  type   by      est    se     x     y
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 te(x,y) Tensor NA     35.3 11.5      2  94.4
 2 te(x,y) Tensor NA     35.5 11.0      2  94.6
 3 te(x,y) Tensor NA     35.7 10.6      2  94.9
 4 te(x,y) Tensor NA     35.9 10.3      2  95.1
 5 te(x,y) Tensor NA     36.2  9.87     2  95.4
 6 te(x,y) Tensor NA     36.4  9.49     2  95.6
 7 te(x,y) Tensor NA     36.6  9.13     2  95.9
 8 te(x,y) Tensor NA     36.8  8.78     2  96.1
 9 te(x,y) Tensor NA     37.0  8.45     2  96.4
10 te(x,y) Tensor NA     37.2  8.13     2  96.6
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

In the output, `x` and `y` are a grid of values over the range of both covariates (the number of points in the grid in each covariate is controlled by `n` such that the grid for a 2d tensor product smooth is of size `n` by `n`). `est` is the estimated value of the smooth at the values of the covariates and `se` its standard error. For models with multiple smooths, the `smooth` variable uses the internal label that {mgcv} gives each smooth - these are the labels used in the output you get from calling `summary()` on your GAM.

We can add a confidence interval if needed using `add_confint()`.

Now you can plot your smooth(s) by hand using `ggplot()`. At this point you have two options

1. if `draw()` can handle the type of smooth you want to plot, you can use the `draw()` method for that object and then build upon it, or
2. plot everything by hand.

#### Option 1

```r
# evaluate just the smooth you want to plot
smooth_estimates(m, smooth = "te(x,y)", dist = 0.1) %>%
draw() +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.2) # add a point layer for original data
```

This pretty much gets you what `draw()` produced when given the model object itself. And you can add to it as if it were a `ggplot` object (which is not the case of the objects returned by `gratia:::draw.gam()`, which is wrapped by {patchwork} and needs other ways to interact with the plots).

#### Option 2

Here you are in full control

```r
sm <- smooth_estimates(m, smooth = "te(x,y)", dist = 0.1)
ggplot(sm, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = est)) +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.2) + # add a point layer for original data
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma")
```

which produces

[image]

A diverging palette is likely better for this, along the lines of the one `gratia:::draw.smooth_estimates` uses

```r
sm <- smooth_estimates(m, smooth = "te(x,y)", dist = 0.1)
ggplot(sm, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = est)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = est), colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.2) + # add a point layer for original data
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", type = "div") +
  expand_limits(fill = c(-1,1) * abs(max(sm[["est"]])))
```

which produces

[image]

Finally, if {gratia} can't handle your model, I'd appreciate you filing a bug report [here](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/issues) so that I can work on supporting as many model types as possible. But do try {mgcViz} as well for an alternative approach to visualsing GAMs fitted using {mgcv}.

Comment: Thank you, Gavin. I'll look into {gratia} again. I know I played around a lot with both {gratia} and {mgcViz}  over the summer, but ended up using ```plot.gam()``` because the others don't plot partial effects from what I understand as I would have to call each term separately instead of throwing the entire model into a plotting function. I have many different terms and displaying partial effects is crucial. (Thanks for catching the y in the tensor product, this was supposed to be z and I updated accordingly)

Comment: {gratia} and {mgcViz} do plot partial effects on the scale of the linear predictor / link function.

Answer (score 0):

Following Gavin Simpson's answer and this thread ([How to add colorbar with perspective plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652941/how-to-add-colorbar-with-perspective-plot-in-r)), I think I've come up with a solution that uses `plot.gam()` (though I really love that {gratia} takes it into a ggplot universe and will definitely look more into that)

```
require(fields)
df.gam<-gam(y~te(x,z), data=df, method='REML')
sm <- as.data.frame(smooth_estimates(df.gam, dist = 0.1))
plot(df.gam, scheme=2, hcolors=heat.colors(999, rev =T), contour.col='black', rug=F,  main='', cex.lab=1.75, cex.axis=1.75)
image.plot(legend.only=T, zlim=range(sm$est), col=heat.colors(999, rev =T), legend.shrink = 0.5, axis.args = list(at =c(-10,-5,0,5, 10, 15, 20)))
```

[image: GAM heatmap with colorbar]

I hope I understood correctly that `gratia:smooth_estimates()` actually pulls out the partial effects.

For my model with multiple terms (and multiple tensor products), this seems to work nicely by indexing the sections of the respective terms in `sm`. Except for one, where the colorbar and the heatmap aren't quite matching up. I can't provide the actual underlaying data, but add that plot for illustration in case anyone has any idea. I'm using the same approach as outlined above. In the colorbar, dark red is at 15-20, but in the heatmap the isolines just above 0 already correspond with the dark red (while 0 is dark yellow'ish in the colorbar).

[image: Mis-matching heatmap and colorbar]

Comment: The expand_limits that I'm doing is a trick in ggplot-verse to centre the diverging palette at 0 (where I want white). I suspect that in your attempts to transfer this to base plot realm, you're changing the limits of the colour bar but not the plot. You'd be better off using `image.plot` directly...